# Como formatar variável de data no Smarty para dd/mm/YYYY

Tags: template

Estou tentando formatar uma data no `Smarty` que está nesse formato `{$Grid.Row.DataEmissao.DisplayValue}` sendo exibida assim: `15-03-2018`, como posso formata-la para `15/03/2018` para exibir em meu relatório, até li em alguns documentos, mas o que vi foi isso:

```
{$smarty.now|date_format}
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%A, %B %e, %Y"}
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%H:%M:%S"}
{$yesterday|date_format}
{$yesterday|date_format:"%A, %B %e, %Y"}
{$yesterday|date_format:"%H:%M:%S"}
MOSTRA:
Feb 6, 2001
Tuesday, February 6, 2001
14:33:00
Feb 5, 2001
Monday, February 5, 2001
14:33:00
```

Mas no meu caso, não resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O smarty usas algumas funções padrões do php para algumas coisas como no caso de datas `strftime()` a regra de formatação é a mesma, conforme consta na [documentação](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)

> date_format is essentially a wrapper to PHP's strftime() function. You may have more or less conversion specifiers available depending on your system's strftime() function where PHP was compiled.

```
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y"}
```

Comment: Excelente, valeu pela dica @rray.